# Downloading a file in the current View, or in a new one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

It is necessary that the file is downloaded either staying on the current page, or a new one opens. Tell me how to do it. Here is what has already been done.

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
        {
            FilesDB filesDB = _context.FilesDB.Find(id);
            filesDB.DownloadCount++;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            string downloadName= filesDB.FileDisplayName +
               Path.GetExtension(filesDB.FilePath);
            return File(filesDB.FilePath, filesDB.FileType, downloadName);            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download both way. Just use HTML form.

Here I'm using WebService:

```
    <form id="downloadForm" action="MyService.asmx/DownloadFile" method="post" target="_self" >
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="txtID" />
    </form>
```

JS:

```
function downloadFile() {
    $('#txtID').val(id);
    $('#downloadForm').submit();
}
```

Just call downloadFile() and this will download staying on current page.
If you want to open in new one just change **target="_self"** to **target="_blank"**

Comment: Thanks. I seem to have discovered what my problem is. When downloading, preloader is called, so far I have removed it and everything works as it should. I will think about how to avoid calling it when downloading.